# Dropdown list in view from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my View , and it's not working...

```
@model PASKAN.Web.Security.Models.User
<p class="lan-name"><label>Language</label>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.Language, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum)).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }))</p>
```

my language Model is as follows

```
public enum Language {
    English = 0,
    Spanish=1,
    Latin =3
}
```

My controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    Models.User user = new User(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name));
    ViewBag.Languages = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Language)).ToList();
    return View (user);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stuffed the languages in the ViewBag, so use them in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.Language, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Languages)
```

but make sure that you have used the correct type that the helper expects:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    Models.User user = new User(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name));
    ViewBag.Languages = Enum
        .GetNames(typeof(Language))
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x, Text = x })
        .ToList();
    return View (user);
}
```

But since you mentioned something about a view model, I think you are misusing this term. In your case I can't see any trace of a view model. A view model would have looked like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action would have passed to the view:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var user = new User(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name));
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        Language = user.Language,
        Languages = Enum
            .GetNames(typeof(Language))
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x, Text = x })
            .ToList()
    };
    return View (viewModel);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Language, Model.Languages)
```